# Megaparsec, backtracking user state with StateT and ParsecT

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

Using Megaparsec 5.
Following [this guide](https://mrkkrp.github.io/megaparsec/tutorials/switch-from-parsec-to-megaparsec.html), I can achieve a back-tracking user-state by combining `StateT` and `ParsecT` (non-defined types should be obvious/irrelevant):

```
type MyParser a = StateT UserState (ParsecT Dec T.Text Identity) a
```

if I run a parser `p :: MyParser a`, like this:

```
parsed = runParser (runStateT p initialUserState) "" input
```

The type of `parsed` is:

```
Either (ParseError Char Dec) (a, UserState)
```

Which means, in case of error, the user state is lost.

Is there any way to have it in both cases?

**EDIT:**
Could I perhaps, in case of error, use a custom error component instead of Dec (a feature introduced in 5.0) and encapsulate the user state in there?

Comment: does it work if you try composing your monad stack differently? `ParsecT Dec T.Text (StateT UserState) a`

Comment: In this case the state would be available at the end of parsing, but it would not be back-tracking with the parser.

Comment: The type of `runStateT p initialUserState` is `Parser (a, UserState)` - conceptually this could just be the parser which unconditionally fails and never produces a value, so the 'state' doesn't exist - what could such a function produce in this case? Surely not `(UserState, Either (..) (a, UserState))`.

Comment: @user2407038 the state would exist in any case, why not? If the parser fails immediately, it would probably be the initial user state. But I agree that the function signature would look odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom error component combined with the `observing` function for this purpose (see [this great post](https://mrkkrp.github.io/posts/latest-additions-to-megaparsec.html) for more information):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Main where

import Text.Megaparsec
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

data MyState = MyState Int deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)
data MyErrorComponent = MyErrorComponent (Maybe MyState) deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)

instance ErrorComponent MyErrorComponent where
    representFail _ = MyErrorComponent Nothing 
    representIndentation _ _ _= MyErrorComponent Nothing 

type Parser = StateT MyState (Parsec MyErrorComponent String)

trackState :: Parser a -> Parser a
trackState parser = do
    result <- observing parser -- run parser but don't fail right away
    case result of
        Right x -> return x -- if it succeeds we're done here
        Left ParseError {..} -> do
            state <- get -- read the current state to add it to the error component
            failure errorUnexpected errorExpected $
                if Set.null errorCustom then Set.singleton (MyErrorComponent $ Just state) else errorCustom
```

In the above snipped, `observing` functions a bit like a `try`/`catch` block that catches a parse error, then reads the current state and adds the it to the custom error component. The custom error component in turn is returned when `runParser` returns a `ParseError`.

Here's a demonstration how this function could be used:

```
a = trackState $ do
    put (MyState 6)
    string "foo"

b = trackState $ do
    put (MyState 5)
    a

main = putStrLn (show $ runParser (runStateT b (MyState 0)) "" "bar")
```

In reality you would probably want to do something more clever (for instance I imagine you could also add the entire stack of states you go through while traversing the stack).

Answer (score 1):

You could try sandwiching `ParserT` between two `State`s, like

```
type MyParser a = StateT UserState (ParsecT Dec T.Text (State UsersState)) a
```

And write special-purpose `put` and `modify` operations that, after changing the outer state, copy the entire state into the inner `State` monad using `put`.

That way, even if parsing fails, you'll have the last "state before failure" available from the inner `State` monad.

Comment: This is precisely what I have been doing so far with Parsec. I was just hoping that Megaparsec could make things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar problem. I use default typing state:

```
type SubDefPos = Int
type SubDefName = String

data MyParserSt = MyParserSt {
   subDefs :: [(SubDefPos, SubDefName)]
} 

ParsecT Void String (StateT MyParserSt Identity) Expr
```

Every change to user state is supplied with the value of `getOffset` to be able to reject later if current position is less than position from the state.